# My android game crashes when loads a new scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My android game crashes when loads a new scene. In unity editor the new level loads ok, but in android device crashes. This is the error that appears in the Android device Monitor when I test it. Can anybody help me to solve it?

```
09-28 13:36:25.223: A/libc(27014): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9c in tid 27046 (UnityMain)
09-28 13:36:25.374: W/ActivityManager(847):   Force finishing activity 1 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
09-28 13:36:25.474: W/InputDispatcher(847): channel '1a8f2147 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
09-28 13:36:25.474: E/InputDispatcher(847): channel '1a8f2147 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-28 13:36:25.520: I/WindowState(847): WIN DEATH: Window{1a8f2147 u0 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}
09-28 13:36:25.520: W/InputDispatcher(847): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '1a8f2147 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)'
```

Comment: Did you check that the scene that are you trying to load is in the build settings?

Comment: Yes. the scene I'm trying to load is in the build settings

Comment: Do you have dynamic batching enabled? In most cases, that's the problem for this (example, here: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/attempted-to-unregister-already-unregistered-input-channel.230822/).

Comment: No, I don't have  dynamic batching enabled. In unity editor the new level loads ok, but in android device crashes

Comment: Are you doing something that might cause discrepancy between the two scenes ? like saving and loading context data and such ? Just as a test, try to make a new project that change to the next scene while pressing a button and see if it work. This way you can tell if it's at least related to the new scene you are loading or to the device / build settings.

Comment: @Pievis In the first scene I have a plane attached to the camera as a child in wich the camera projects the image of the telephone camera. I've tested to delete this plane and the next scene loads ok. But I need this plane. What can I do?

Comment: it's just an hunch, but try to set the object to not be destroyed during the loading of the new scene. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: @Pievis I think I 've found the solution. I'm using WebCamTexture to display the telephone camera in a plane and it's producing the error

Comment: good job ! if you found the problem reply o your thread with an answer, this way you might help others in the future.